# Update variable in every tick using setInterval() with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to count up a variable every x seconds in JS using setInterval() and show it in my view binding this variable the Angular way. The problem is, in the model the var is counted up but the progress is just shown as soon as I stop the Interval. How can I update the var in the view on every tick?

```
<span>{{number}}</span>
```

and:

```
$scope.number = 0;
$scope.interval;

$scope.run = function(){
    $scope.interval = setInterval(function(){
        $scope.number++;
    }, 1000);
};

$scope.stop = function(){
    clearInterval($scope.interval);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TipNo1/yvpmkgq4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using Angular's implementation of `setInterval` called [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Not only will this will ensure any code within the callback calls a digest, but it will also help you easily test your code:

```
$scope.run = function() {
    $scope.interval = $interval(function() {
        $scope.number++;
    }, 1000);
};
$scope.stop = function() {
    $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
};
```

I would also avoid attaching your `interval` variable to the `$scope`. I can't see any reason your view would need to be aware of it. A private `var interval` in the controller scope would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.number = 0;

    $scope.run = function (){
        $scope.interval = $interval(function(){ 
            $scope.number++;
        }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.stop = function() {
        $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
    };
```

});